# ORA-00001: unique constraint violated with batchUpdate but with update all good

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have an interesting problem. Using spring boot and jdbctemplate. I have two SQLs. The first SQL creates the record and the primaryKey is retrieved. A second SQL attempt to create another table is written using the already created primaryKey and an error is received. It is interesting that second SQL with `batchUpdate` an error is received, but with simple `update` no error is received. Both sqls are running one after the other and both are running in the same transaction. Why is this happening and what is the best way to fix it

```
public int[] createMultilpleRow(String carId, List<String> houseIds) {
    List<MapSqlParameterSource> sqlParameterSources = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String houseId : houseIds) {
        MapSqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        sqlParameterSource.addValue("CAR_ID", carId);
        sqlParameterSource.addValue("HOUSE_ID", houseId);
        sqlParameterSources.add(sqlParameterSource);
    }
    SqlParameterSource[] batch = new SqlParameterSource[sqlParameterSources.size()];
    sqlParameterSources.toArray(batch);

    return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("""
            INSERT INTO TABLE (carId, houseId)
            VALUES (:carId, :houseId)
            """, batch);
}

 public int createResource(String carId) {
    Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    arguments.put("CAR_ID", carId);
   
    return jdbcTemplate.update("""
            INSERT INTO CarTable (carId)
            VALUES (:carId)
            """, arguments);
}
```

Comment: you can enrich your question with snippet of the code ?

Comment: Yes, I will. Added

Comment: Can  we see what you declared as primary key in your DB ? The ORA-00001 message is triggered when a unique constraint has been violated. Maybe you pass a duplicate values in your batch or retring to save what are you already saved in the update.

Comment: Looks like my batchUpdate some how working outside transaction scope and can't find this ID